# uninitialized constant CURL::URI (NameError)

Tags: ruby, curl, uri, nameerror

I'm using [CURL gem](https://github.com/tg0/curl/) in order to mask http request with a proxy server and send some requests:

```
require 'curl'

curl = CURL.new
curl.proxy('114.26.9.171:8888')
curl.get('http://google.com')
```

However when I'm trying to pass the proxy param to curl instance it throws out the following error:

```
gems/curl-0.0.9/lib/curl.rb:64:in `proxy': uninitialized constant CURL::URI (NameError)
```

What can be the reason of this error?
I've checked the curl.rb file and found that all necessary libraries are
required:

```
require 'cgi'
require "open3"
require 'fileutils' 
require 'ap' 
require 'digest/md5'
require 'string_cleaner'
require 'open-uri'

...

    def proxy(proxy_uri)
      File.open("/tmp/aaaaaaaa.aaa","w"){|file| file.puts "#{Time.now}---"+proxy_uri}
        proxy = ( proxy_uri.is_a?(URI) ? proxy_uri : URI.parse("http://#{proxy_uri}") )
      @setup_params = "#{@setup_params} --proxy \"#{proxy.host}:#{proxy.port}\" "
        @setup_params = "#{@setup_params} --proxy-user \"#{proxy.user}:#{proxy.password}\" " if proxy.user
    end
```

What can be the reason of this error and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. So the [current] version you're looking at in github is not the same as the version that's packed in the gem.

Look at:
https://github.com/tg0/curl/blob/5556b052fd4f2970256862b1b17a6d4b1a6ee3ef/lib/curl.rb

Basically it's missing the uri require. Try adding that before requiring 'curl' and see if that makes it work.